# Statistical test for differences in proportions, over-dispersed count data

Tags: proportion, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I have a nxm contingency table where I have counts of elements divided by type. For example:

[image]

I would like to know if the proportions of any of the columns are different (i.e., is the G1/G2 proportion different for T1 vs. T2). I thought a Fisher's exact might be appropriate, but (1) my numbers are quite large (100s-10,000s), (2) in some cases I have up to 26 T columns, (3) there is overdispersion that I would like to account for.

Any advice on statistical tests for this?

Comment: How can you tell there's overdispersion in the conditional distributions?

Comment: Why do you say there's over-dispersion? There are no replicates in the design you present that would allow it to be distinguished from the effects you're interested in.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that we do have replicates but I planned on pooling them for this analysis. This is actually a RNA-sequencing (gene expression) dataset which is a dataset that suffers generally from an overdispersion problem. G1/G2 measures are taken from the same individuals.